# Why is getline (from a file) to cout (that line) not printing the line?

Tags: c++, file, output, cout, getline

This is my code here.

```
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

string line, line2;

inFile.open("DATA.txt");
outFile.open("DATA.txt");

getline(inFile, line);
cout << line;
getline(inFile, line2);
cout << line2;

getline(cin, line);
getline(cin, line2);

outFile << line << "\n" << line2;
```

From what I understand, getline(inFile, line) should assign the first line of my text file to a string named line. Then the cout << line should print that string into the cmd window. This is not working though.

I am able to input just fine using getline(cin, line) and outFile though. The file gets updated and I can see what I typed in it, but it just doesn't properly read and print the lines.

p.s This is my first question and I'm not entirely sure how to ask it in the title so I'm open to criticism.

Comment: Maybe its not reading your file because you have it in the wrong folder.

Comment: Why are you trying to open the same file twice? Why not just open it once for both reading and writing?

Comment: Always make sure your file `is_open()` before you try and read it.

Comment: You should check for errors after opening and reading from the files. That would give you clues what might be going wrong.

Comment: Opening a file for output deletes the file contents by default (truncates). That would be my guess why this is not doing what you expect. You delete the file before you read its contents.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects to a meaningful state when you create them. Change `ifstream inFile; ... infile.open("DATA.txt");` to `ifstream inFile("DATA.txt");`. And don't bother with `infile.close();` (if that's off the end of the code excerpt); the destructor will do that.

Comment: I recommend using `fstream::open` and opening the file in read *and* write mode (`ios::in | ios::out`).  There may be some underlying conflicts when declaring two stream objects to the same file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If he does that, he also need to remember to rewind and truncate when he rewrites the file. So either way there are complications.

Answer (score 0):

On most platforms, `std::cout` typically buffers output data and does not flush to the console until a line break is output, or the buffer is flushed explicitly.

Try using:

```
cout << line << '\n';
```

Or:

```
cout << line << endl;
```

If you don't want to output line breaks, use:

```
cout << line << flush;
```

Comment: The buffer will be flushed when the program exits, so he should see the output eventually.

Comment: Eventually, but maybe that doesn't happen for awhile in the OP's case, we don't know since a complete program was not provided.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. When I had

```
inFile.open("DATA.txt");
outFile.open("DATA.txt");
```

I think the outFile.open overwrote the inFile.open, causing only the output part to work. 
Simply moving the outFile.open to before the output part instead of before everything fixed this problem. I'm sure there are several other sloppy things about my code, but that fixed it to the point of actually working.